# How to break out of script using invoke-expression

Tags: powershell, break

I have a powershell script that works like a menu. After making a choice, it starts another powershell script.

The other scripts are fairly large, and I have many points in the scripts where I need to abort that script and return back to the menu.

I call the other scripts using:

```
invoke-expression -Command "& '.\script.ps1'"
```

In the script itself, at various locations, I use the following command to break out of the script.

```
break script
```

This works well, as it terminates the script, but it does not return to the previous invoked script.

The break command with parameter means that it breaks to a label. If no label is present it will break out of the entire script. But given how I invoke the script currently, it sees everything as one big script and breaks out of everything.

In my subscript, I placed the following at the end of the file:

```
:End_Of_Script
```

and used break End_Of_Script but that fails the same.

**So my question is boiling down to this:
How can I invoke another script and at any point break out of that script and return back to the previous script without altering the complete structure of that script?**

Here's a snippet of what the subscript is:

```
write-host "1. Choice A"
write-host "2. Choice B"
$choice = read-host "What choice?"

switch ($choice)
1
{
     write-host "The choice is A"
}

2
{
     write-host "The choice is B"
}
default
{
     write-host "Invalid choice"
     break script
}

get-childitem | foreach-object {

    if( $_.Name -like "*test*")
    {
         break script
    }

}
```

In my main script, the commands after `invoke-expression ...` are never executed.

Comment: Why not simply dot-source the other script: `. '.\script.ps1'`

Comment: Labels can only be applied to loop statements, you can't just drop `:somelabel` anywhere in the script and expect `break` to work like a `goto` statement

Comment: @Theo what would be the implication of doing that, vs what I am doing now?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, I found that out myself. Do you know a way to work around this?

Comment: @LPChip I'm afraid I don't understand what (and why) you're trying to do well enough to answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exit` to do this.

> The exit keyword is best used in functions, and when those functions are called in a script. It's a great way to terminate execution of functions.

reference [PowerShell Exit Function & Code Execution | Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/powershell-terminating-code-execution)

---

If the script encounters an error and needs to exit, `throw` can be used to better prompt the specific cause of the error.

---

Calling another script can be done with `& $FilePath`, `invoke-expression -Command "& '$FilePath'"` is a cumbersome and unnecessary usage.